# How to read ASB status in python-escpos

Tags: python, escpos

I want to read back ASB and other status results in python-escpos.  I thought the ._read() method would work but I get a "AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute '_read'" error.  I have verified the _read() method is there with inspect.

Any suggestion on how I can read back status's in python-escpos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try specifying the `GS a` command as a parameter in the `query_status()` method and calling it.

[GS a](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=122)

> ```
> [Name]
> Enable/disable Automatic Status Back (ASB)
> [Format]
> ASCII   GS  a   n
> Hex     1D  61  n
> Decimal 29  97  n
> [Range]
> n = 0 – 255
> [Default]
> n: different depending on the printers
> ```

Please try by specifying 0xFF for `n`.

[query_status(mode)](https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/methods.html#escpos.escpos.Escpos.query_status)

> Queries the printer for its status, and returns an array of integers containing it.
>
> Parameters: mode – Integer that sets the status mode queried to the printer. - RT_STATUS_ONLINE: Printer status. - RT_STATUS_PAPER: Paper sensor.
>   Return type: array(integer)

[def query_status(self, mode):](https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/escpos/escpos.html#Escpos.query_status)

> ```
> def query_status(self, mode):
>     """
>     Queries the printer for its status, and returns an array of integers containing it.
>     :param mode: Integer that sets the status mode queried to the printer.
>         - RT_STATUS_ONLINE: Printer status.
>         - RT_STATUS_PAPER: Paper sensor.
>     :rtype: array(integer)
>     """
>     self._raw(mode)
>     time.sleep(1)
>     status = self._read()
>     return status
> ```

[def _raw(self, msg):](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos/blob/0c0e6b9b4c1fe596bb1c3fdac3e30276e8c1f7d5/src/escpos/printer.py#L95)

> ```
> def _raw(self, msg):
>     """ Print any command sent in raw format
>     :param msg: arbitrary code to be printed
>     :type msg: bytes
>     """
>     self.device.write(self.out_ep, msg, self.timeout)
> ```

[def _read(self):](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos/blob/0c0e6b9b4c1fe596bb1c3fdac3e30276e8c1f7d5/src/escpos/printer.py#L103)

> ```
> def _read(self):
>     """ Reads a data buffer and returns it to the caller. """
>     return self.device.read(self.in_ep, 16)
> ```

[# Status Command](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos/blob/0051c876bfe70fac321b3a11f61e5b0340d4b0f2/src/escpos/constants.py#L271)

> ```
> RT_STATUS = DLE + EOT
> RT_STATUS_ONLINE = RT_STATUS +  b'\x01'
> RT_STATUS_PAPER = RT_STATUS +  b'\x04'
> RT_MASK_ONLINE = 8
> RT_MASK_PAPER = 18
> RT_MASK_LOWPAPER = 30
> RT_MASK_NOPAPER = 114
> ```

Comment: Thanks, It looks like my problem was that I have python2 installed with python-Thanks for the help.  It look like my problem was that I had different versions of python-escpos installed. python2 had escpos 3.04a and python3 had 2.20.  When I opened a shell I got python2 with python-escpos 3.04a and _read() was there.  When I ran my scripts it used Python3 and there was no _read().